# A prolog program to group cities

Tags: prolog

Please I need help here, it's an assigment

A prolog program that shows which cities are in south-

east of Nigeria. Here are the cities (abraka, oyo, awka,

orlu, markurdi, jalingo, owerri, aba, mushin, okigwe).

```
abraka (city not in south-east)
oyo (city not in south-east)
awka (city in south-east)
orlu (city in south-east)
markudi (city not in south-east)
jalingo (city not in south-east)
owerri (city in south-east)
aba (city in south-east)
mushin (city not in south-east)
okaigwe (city in south-east)
```

Please I don't know exactly what to do. Thanks for any

help.

Comment: It's been a while since I last did anything in Prolog, but that doesn't look like Prolog code to me. Did you get any predicates you were supposed to use? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the first things you shall do with a (prolog) problem is to choose a suitable representation for your data according to what queries you will need.

In this case, you will need to have a predicate like is_city_in_south_east(City).
Therefore, you could represent your data as:

```
is_city_in_SOuth_east(abraka).
is_city_in_south_east(awka).
city_is_not_in_south_east(oyo).
....
```

however, this representation is too specific.
something more general would be

```
city_location(abraka, south_east).
city_location(awka).
city_location(oyo, not_south_east).
```

I assumed that the

```
abraka (city not in south-east)
oyo (city not in south-east)
awka (city in south-east)
orlu (city in south-east)
markudi (city not in south-east)
jalingo (city not in south-east)
owerri (city in south-east)
aba (city in south-east)
mushin (city not in south-east)
okaigwe (city in south-east)
```

was just a human-readable representation of the database.

In case this is the actual input of your program you (in a text file for example) it's quite messy; I think that the easiest way is to build a mini-parser.